# How to disable coop in Rayman Origins??

Tags: pc, rayman-origins

I have installed **Rayman Origins** in my PC and I am using a gaming controller.
Everything works fine but when I hit Enter from Keyboard it gives another player (Coop) and I dont want that.

Is there any way to disable that??

Comment: Press enter again? On consoles dropping out is the same button as dropping in.

Comment: I'm curious: why do you hit Enter in the first place?

Comment: Most likely you'd need to change the keyboard bindings, so instead of enter, it would be a different button. I don't think you can fully disable it